# jquery img and desc swap

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to swap an img src and a text description with jquery.  This is what i have so far but now working of course :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideShow a").click(function() {
        var imgTitle = $(this).children('img').attr('title'); // Find the image title
        $("#thecap").html(' ' + imgTitle + ' ');
        $("#lgImage").attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('rel'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Please put your code inside code tags (The double brace button on the textbox)

Comment: it's better to paste your js code in http://jsfiddle.net and explain it here.

Comment: i did. when i copy and past into the double brace this is what happens

Comment: ive modified.  this doenst work either.  what i click an "a" element withing the slideshow div i want to swap the lgImage src with the info in the "rel" element as well as swap the html description with whats in the "title" element

Comment: The above code now works.  forgot the document.ready stuff.  once that was in it all came together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the get `.attr('src')` and try to set a value to it. The last line should be:

```
$("#lgImage").attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('rel'));
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

> #### .attr( attributeName, value )
>
> `attributeName`The name of the
>   attribute to set.
>
> `value` A value to set for the
>   attribute.